# Cool widgets for a Custom GUI in python/pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, python-2.x

I was wondering what cool ideas anyone has had for some widgets. By widgets I mean those things in windows vista that feed you information (clock, ect.). Another example would be something like a twitter feed or a quick search bar. This is going into my custom GUI written in Python with Pygame. "JupeeShell" is the name of it.

Here is what it looks like right now, there is one for the mac but it doesn't work yet, nor linux, just Windows as of now.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/wvxtvqacabrpuac/JupeeGUIFiles_2.zip
Notice how you can put images on your normal Windows desktop (.png, .jpg, and .jpeg) and they show up on the JupeeShell Desktop over on the right side?
Any widget ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: also this is using Python 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

weather,calculator,slideshow,battery percentage,wifi status(network,signal strength),cpu percentage, traffic report